# How do you align a div vertically without using float?

Tags: html, css

When doing something like this:

```
<div style="float: left;">Left Div</div>
<div style="float: right;">Right Div</div>
```

I have to use an empty div with

```
clear: both;
```

which feels very dirty to me.

So, is there a way to align without the use of float?

Here is my code:

```css
.action_buttons_header a.green_button{
 
}
```

```html
<div class="change_requests_container" style="width:950px !important">
    <div class="sidebar">
        
            
                <a href="/view/preview_unpublished_revision/422?klass=Proposal" class="preview sidebar_button_large action_button" name="preview" onclick="window.open(this.href);return false;">Preview New Version</a>
            
        
        
    </div>
    <div class="content_container">
        <div class="content">
                        
                <div class="action_buttons_header">
                    <a href="/changes/merge_changes/422" class="re_publish publish green_button" style="
    margin: 5px 0px 5px auto;
">Apply Changes</a>
                </div>
            
            


            <div id="change_list_container">    

<div class="changes_table">
    
        
            
            <style type="text/css">
                #original_492 .rl_inline_added {
                    display: none;
                }
                
                #492.change_container .actial_suggested_text_container{
                    display: none;
                }
            </style>
            <div class="content_section_header_container">
                <div class="content_section_header">
                    <a href="#" class="collapse" name="492"></a>
                    The Zerg | 
                    Overview
                    <div class="status" id="492_status">
                        <div id="492_status_placeholder">
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="change_container" id="492">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the green button on the right of the horizontal bar that it's in but in the cleanest way possible.

Just trying to learn how to do CSS elegantly, cleanly, etc.

Comment: if your just trying to eliminate the empty `div` then you could use a [clear fix](http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/02/05/lessons-learned-concerning-the-clearfix-css-hack/) `class`

Answer (score 64, accepted):

In you case here, if you want to right-align that green button, just change the one div to have everything right-aligned:

```
<div class="action_buttons_header" style="text-align: right;">
```

The div is already taking up the full width of that section, so just shift the green button the right by right-aligning the text.

Comment: I tried this... and it works ok... but the button won't have a vertical margin to push it down to it's centered vertically. maybe something else is the issue http://jsfiddle.net/58pRG/2/

Comment: Add line-height: 38px; to the header class:  .action_buttons_header{
     text-align: right;
    line-height: 38px;
}

Answer (score 71):

Another way to do something similar is with flexbox on a wrapper element, i.e.,

```css
 .row {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="row">
        <div>Left</div>
        <div>Right</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: flex is a display option? O.o https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display WOAH. THERE ARE SO MANY since I last checked.

Comment: The browser support is fairly good as well, though occasionally you do need to prefix it.  This is a very good site for learning flex: http://flexboxfroggy.com/

Comment: @myrcutio Thanks so much for this. Did exactly what I needed and is very clean.

Comment: @myrcutio plus 1

Comment: This is brilliant!

Answer (score 19):

you could use things like `display: inline-block` but I think you would need to set up another div to move it over, if there is nothing going to the left of the button you could use margins to move it into place.

Alternatively but not a good solution, you could position tags; put the encompassing div as `position: relative` and then the div of the button as `position: absolute; right: 0`, but like I said this is probably not the best solution

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
  <div>Left Div</div>
  <div class="right">Right Div</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
.right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: I honestly find this to be the best solution. Display block outter container to fill the space, display inline-block inner container to text-align right, skip all of the float headache and still get nice things like margin and padding.

Comment: I like (and upvoted) this, too, but indeed, has drawbacks, a serious one being that `absolute` will remove `.right` from calculating the dimensions of `.parent`, so in case it's a container of similarly `absolute` sibling elements (e.g. in my case some window control widgets), then .parent will just collapse as if it was empty.

Answer (score 13):

It is dirty better use the `overflow: hidden;` hack:

```
<div class="container">
  <div style="float: left;">Left Div</div>
  <div style="float: right;">Right Div</div>
</div>

.container { overflow: hidden; }
```

Or if you are going to do some fancy CSS3 drop-shadow stuff and you get in trouble with the above solution:

http://web.archive.org/web/20120414135722/http://fordinteractive.com/2009/12/goodbye-overflow-clearing-hack

PS

If you want to go for clean I would rather worry about that inline javascript rather than the `overflow: hidden;` hack :)

Comment: why does it have to be a hack, though? isn't there some proper, clean way to do it?

Comment: @TheLindyHop not reliable no :-) But at least with the `overflow: hidden` hack you don't have to add extra (non-semantical) elements.

Comment: idk, I'll play around a bit. And as for the inline js, the app I'm working is very much an in-progress thing. And it's very modular, so sometimes there needs to be inline js that is executed when a ajax replace is called =D

Comment: @TheLindyHop those are not really reasons to use inline js. Actually there isn't any good reason to ever do it IMHO :-)

Comment: ruby on rails' link_to and link_to_remote use it =\

Comment: @PeeHaa the question clearly mentions without using float

Comment: @PeeHaa the question is `How do you align left / right a div without using float?`

Comment: @visakhsujathan there is blindly answering the question like many SO monkeys nowadays do. And there is solving the actual problem of OP and readers.

Answer (score 10):

Another solution could be something like following (works depending on your element's display property):

HTML:

```
<div class="left-align">Left</div>
<div class="right-align">Right</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left-align {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.right-align {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Very cool solution and doesn't require a wrapping element or add styles to the parent element.

Comment: "works depending on your element's display property" - in which configuration does it work? I supposed parent is `block`, and children are `inline-block`... But then it just did the same as without any margins (unsurprisingly).

Answer (score 5):

Very useful thing have applied today in my project. One div had to be aligned right, with no floating applied.

Applying code made my goal achieved:

```
.div {
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: This only work with flexbox/grid parent

Answer (score 3):

You could just use a margin-left with a percentage.

HTML

```
<div class="goleft">Left Div</div>
<div class="goright">Right Div</div>
```

CSS

```
.goright{
    margin-left:20%;
}
.goleft{
    margin-right:20%;
}
```

(goleft would be the same as default, but can reverse if needed)

text-align doesn't always work as intended for layout options, it's mainly just for text. (But is often used for form elements too).

The end result of doing this will have a similar effect to a div with float:right; and width:80% set. Except, it won't clump together like a float will. (Saving the default display properties for the elements that come after).

Answer (score 1):

No need to add extra elements. While flexbox uses very non-intuitive property names if you know what it *can* do you'll find yourself using it quite often.

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
<span>Item Left</span>
<span>Item Right</span>
</div>
```

Plan on needing this often?

```
.align_between {display: flex; justify-content: space-between;}
```

I see other people using secondary words in the primary position which makes a mess of information hierarchy. If *align* is the primary task and *right*, *left*, and/or *between* are the secondary the class *should* be `.align_outer`, *not* `.outer_align` as it will make sense as you vertically scan your code:

```
.align_between {}
.align_left {}
.align_outer {}
.align_right {}
```

Good habits over time will allow you to get to bed sooner than later.